# Add class to div when he visible

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I add class to some element (`<div>`) when those on visible on a screen or maybe his position in the center of the screen and remove this class when the page scrolled down or up?

Comment: can you please add some code and so we might get idea what you have done till yet and problem you are facing easily !!

Comment: @NalinAggarwal For example i have this structure:
https://jsfiddle.net/q0h3L201/

When this element is on screen i need add class .active to div with class .text-block

Comment: It's Better if you update you question with these details. I added the link not other details

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try This.

```js
$.fn.visible = function(partial) {

  var $t = $(this),
    $w = $(window),
    viewTop = $w.scrollTop(),
    viewBottom = viewTop + $w.height(),
    _top = $t.offset().top,
    _bottom = _top + $t.height(),
    compareTop = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
    compareBottom = partial === true ? _top : _bottom;

  return ((compareBottom <= viewBottom) && (compareTop >= viewTop));
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
  checkVisible();
});

$(window).scroll(function(e) {
  checkVisible();
});


function checkVisible() {
  $('.box').each(function(i, k) {
    if ($(this).visible()) {
      $(k).addClass('box-active');
    } else {
      $(k).removeClass('box-active');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.grid2x2 {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.grid2x2>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 40px);
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.grid2x2>div>div {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.box {
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: black;
}

.box-active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="grid2x2">
  <div class="box box1">
    <div>one</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box2">
    <div>two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box3">
    <div>three</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box4">
    <div>four</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box5">
    <div>five</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box6">
    <div>two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box7">
    <div>three</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box8">
    <div>four</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box9">
    <div>one</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box10">
    <div>two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box11">
    <div>three</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box12">
    <div>four</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box13">
    <div>one</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box14">
    <div>two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box15">
    <div>three</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box16">
    <div>four</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box17">
    <div>one</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box18">
    <div>two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box19">
    <div>three</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box20">
    <div>four</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box21">
    <div>one</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box22">
    <div>two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box23">
    <div>three</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box24">
    <div>four</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box25">
    <div>one</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box26">
    <div>two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box27">
    <div>three</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box28">
    <div>four</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What is the problem and how does your code solve it?